# Change Slicehost operating system without losing data

Tags: ubuntu, slicehost

I want to change the operating system on a Slicehost VPS.  I'd like to do this in the least painful way possible, so I'm trying to figure out a way to do it without building a new slice from scratch using the new OS.

If it matters, I am switching from the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 10.04 to the 32 bit version.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You're going the wrong way! Why do you want to change down to 32bit?

Comment: You can still run 32-bit binaries on 64-bit provided the 32bit libraries are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a backup. Even if there's a simple way to do this, you don't want to even attempt it without a backup. Personally I'd recommend creating a new slice, migrating your data across and then asking slicehost to either swap the IPs if they're in the same range, or swap the slices over.